# Male colleague using female bathroom and not cleaning up

Tags: colleagues, netherlands

I work in a growing company with only 1 bathroom for women, and 1 for men. The bathrooms are always occupied and everyone needs to wait from time to time.

My male colleague uses the female bathroom, specifically to 'go number two'. Normally I wouldn't really mind a man using the bathroom, as we all do the same business in there, but the issue is he always leaves the toilet dirty and smelling, even though a toilet brush and spray are provided.

He acts like he 'mistakenly' used the women's bathroom when you run into him. They are clearly labeled. He just says 'oh no, wrong door.'

A note asking people to leave the toilet cleaner has already been put up but this didn't help and I'm not sure of my HR manager knows it's him leaving the mess.

I am not comfortable telling him directly. Should I 'tell on him' to HR?

Comment: When bathrooms are in small numbers, the problem is not him using another room(if the other one is always full). The problem is him leaving a terrible mess.

Comment: This seems to be more about leaving the bathroom dirty than which bathroom he uses.

Comment: The discussion about gender has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43464/discussion-on-question-by-janedoe1337-male-colleague-using-female-bathroom-and-n).  Please take all discussion of gender-segregated bathrooms, gender identity, and which gender is messier there.  As a reminder, once we've created a room from a post we can't add comments to it, so further comments on those topics will be deleted.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Talk to your boss or manager.**

There is a good chance your boss will have an opinion on this. In my office there is almost always a women's bathroom open to use.  There is only one woman who uses it.  But my boss was adamant that it was not to be used by men and it hasn't been a problem. Hopefully your boss will make a standard. At the very least, I'd imagine he say, if you use that bathroom, clean up after yourself.

If you boss is indifferent but okay with you sending out an email, you could send out a general email as a reminder to "Keep things clean".

It's reasonable to expect a clean bathroom space at work. Don't feel embarrassed asking for that.

Comment: One doesn't even have to mention the specific person. Just that it happens.

Comment: It's also reasonable to expect a bathroom that is free to use. "The bathrooms are always occupied' - this is the real problem here. The company might actually get in a serious problem over this. This is Europe, and workers have pretty good guarantees of basic ergonomic rights.

Comment: Don't send the email - they don't work.

Comment: Almost always, sending general communication "Can everyone please do X?" when the problem is known to be one person is a very annoying, poor way to address a problem.  I suppose it's understandable this time just because it is such a sensitive issue.  But I think it's unlikely to solve the problem.  It's the equivalent of the sign that is already in the bathroom.

Answer (score 107):

The problem isn't that somebody is using the wrong bathroom; the problem is leaving it dirty.  If you had unisex bathrooms (meaning there's no "wrong"), or if one of your female colleagues were doing this, you'd still have the cleanliness problem.  So focus on that.

This is something to take to your manager or HR.  Talking directly to the person (which I know you've said you're not comfortable doing anyway) risks (a) making things more uncomfortable and (b) turning the whole thing into a discussion about gender when, really, your problem is the *mess*.

The issue you should take to your manager or HR is: somebody often leaves the bathroom messy; we need to fix that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43488/discussion-between-ronnie-w-and-monica-cellio).

Comment: I have cleaned up the comments, deleted those already moved to chat and removed the comments that were not relevant to the answer.

Comment: @JaneS The current chat is complete incoherant, because it refers to discussion that has since been deleted?  Can the deleted discussion just live on in chat?

Answer (score 34):

I think you are taking too much into your own hands.

You are working there, and you require adequately clean facilities for your comfort, and the company is failing to provide them.

Go to your manager and complain.  "The bathroom is consistently dirty, daily."

If they don't address the issue in a way that resolves the problem - regardless of the cause - then go to HR.  "the bathroom is consistently dirty, daily."

They are responsible for providing clean facilities.  It's not your job to investigate, provide evidence, or find the root cause.  If they choose to do that, that's fine.  If they choose to get a cleaning service (or an employee) to check and clean the toilets more frequently, that's fine.

If they don't resolve the problem, then you may be able to file complaints with your local governments about conditions of employment, but unless body fluids and other excrement are placed in areas you are expected to come into direct contact with (ie, outside the bowl), then it's unlikely that you will receive any relief.  You may need to find another job, or put up with unpleasant scents and sights wif they pose no actual harm to your body.  Perhaps a bathroom scent dispenser may resolve some of your concerns.

Regardless, I'd strongly suggest you drop all concern over who is making the mess, and only concern yourself with how the mess is affecting you, and conveying that concern to the people who are in a position to resolve it.

If you bring up the individual, or the sex of the individual, they may view it as a problem between two employees, or a personal bias on your part against men.  This is not what you want them to focus on - at least not if you want them to take action on the messiness left behind.

Answer (score 17):

There is so much wrong with this whole scenario, I hardly know where to start.

**Company not providing adequate bathrooms**
This is the biggest issue and the rest are being caused by it.  The company needs to provide more bathroom space.  If the bathrooms are constantly full and people are constantaly having to wait, that means that productivity is being lost. I'm not sure about the Netherlands, but in the US there are laws governing this.

**Men using the women's bathroom**
This isn't a huge deal if the bathrooms are single occupancy and it only happens occasionally.  However, the fact that it is happening all the time is going to cause issues.

**Employees being asked to scrub the toilet**
This may be normal in the Netherlands, but it would be very odd in the US.  I've never once worked at a place where employees were expected to scrub the toilet after they used it.  This would be handled at night by the janitorial staff. If this is the norm in the Netherlands, then I would bring it up with your boss or HR.

Comment: It may not be typical here in the states to bring up, but I personally wouldn't have a problem with the boss mentioning that "if you crap all over the seat or leave your feces plastered on the inside walls of the toilet, you should be an *adult* and clean up after yourself". After all, that's why a brush and spray are there and not in a janitors closet. I would also not expect that person to leave their own body that dirty after the fact, so why something that everyone else uses? Ironically, he could be using the women's bathroom because the other males in the office are just as bad or worse.

Comment: Most places I've worked don't leave a toilet brush and cleaner in the bathroom.

Comment: Me neither, but that could be the way it's done in the Netherlands or at this small company who can't afford on-demand/after-use janitorial services. The point is that this guy is acting like a child, and a boss asking the employees to be adults (and providing them the tools for the job) wouldn't be the worst idea, though a bit unusual; because, bad apples. I like your answer and all, just wanted to add that extra point.

Comment: It is indeed the normal thing in the Netherlands to leave a brush in the toilet and all adults (and many kids) are instructed to use it whenever needed. Might be that we use different kinds of toilets from the USA ones, which might require a bit more attention after use.

Comment: @Kevin - even in the US it's pretty common when you look at small businesses, especially the kind that only have ONE bathroom for each sex. Having worked at both small mom & pop places as well as large corporate offices, I've seen the full range. And lemme tell you... I have seen some *#^&.

Comment: In Europe it is not only normal but **expected** from the user to scrub the toilet, actually I'm very surprised reading in this answer that it's not seen as normal everywhere (and we're not even talking about third-world countries, but the USA). Maybe there is a cultural difference too, and the co-worker comes from a place where scrubbing the toilet after use is not considered normal?

Comment: @Val The water pressure in U.S. toilets is usually sufficient to clean the bowl by itself, especially the ones used in public facilities. It is, however, considered polite to clean up anything else that may be left behind or flush more than once if needed to clean the bowl.

Comment: @reirab : In this case, assuming good faith (however negatively the attitude of the co-worker was described) it might happen that he comes from a place where this wasn't a problem, so he just leaves quickly before the flushing finished, assuming everything is OK but in reality it isn't. In Germany, for example, toilets have a different shape and unlikely to clean themselves automatically. Maybe it's similar in the Netherlands? If that's the case, a way should be found to let the coworker know about it without sounding too offensive.

Comment: Yes, expectations on who has to do which cleaning can differ. Our toilets are cleaned every night by a company, but during the day we're expected to leave the bathroom in usable condition for the next person. We have some of these signs in the toilets in our building as a lighthearted reminder: http://im-sitzen-pinkeln.de/ Maybe you can put some of these up as well - they're free to print out for your own use.

Comment: It amuses me that the US has laws against how long you can be expected to wait to take a cr@p, but not against your employer firing you on the spot for no apparent reason ^_^

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It amuses me that in many places in Europe, you are forced to continue working for an employer for weeks or even months after you decide you no longer want to.  I've never once been fired from a job for no apparent reason.  I have however, wanted to quit a terrible job and not have to stay there for another month

Comment: Apparently there are no required numbers for toilets in the law anymore, there should be "sufficient" and a guideline is one for every 15 persons of a given gender -- http://www.arbozone.nl/13919/371-toiletten-en-wastafels . And yeah, the Netherlands does have the same type of toilet as Germany, where the chance of having some cleaning to do is greater than elsewhere. There's always a brush.

Comment: @Val Where in Europe? I'm in the UK and this has never been an expectation anywhere I've worked. I believe US toilets are the same design as UK ones, but I don't remember noticing European ones as being different; never been to Netherlands or Germany though.

Comment: @peterG : make a google search for German-style toilets, and you'll see what's the difference. I've seen them in Germany, Austria, and several Eastern European countries.

Comment: @Val - ah Those! I'd heard rumours, but never seen one! So the different expectations regarding using a brush afterwards now fall into place (as it were).

Comment: @peterG: The first time I wanted to use a toilet somewhere in Los Angeles I thought it was broken and went to the next one which looked equally broken to me - due to very different design.

Comment: I must add that the allegedly German-style toilets are in my experience (30 years) not to be found in Germany outside hospitals and very old buildings. In hospitals they are common because of - er - taking samples...